# Web Scraping Error: Request and No Connection

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to write my first program in python. The intent of the web scraping program is to pull prices from potentially 100 or more websites for multiple types of products. I was able to write the program for one website and have it exported to an excel file with no issue. However, I am now having issues when trying to web scrape multiple sites.

I am trying to place more than one URL into a list, then create a for loop to run the same code for each URL. Below is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Aero Stripped Lowers
url = ['https://www.aeroprecisionusa.com/ar15/lower-receivers/stripped-lowers?product_list_limit=all', 'https://www.aeroprecisionusa.com/ar15/lower-receivers/complete-lowers?product_list_limit=all']
for website in url:
    headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0"}
    page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

#Locating All Stripped Aero Lowers On Site
all_aero_stripped_lowers = soup.find(class_='products wrapper container grid products-grid')
items = all_aero_stripped_lowers.find_all(class_='product-item-info')

#Identifying All Aero Stipped Lower Names And Prices
aero_stripped_lower_names = [item.find(class_='product-item-link').text for item in items]
aero_stripped_lower_prices = [item.find(class_='price').text for item in items]


Aero_Stripped_Lowers_Consolidated = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Aero Stripped Lower': aero_stripped_lower_names,
     'Prices': aero_stripped_lower_prices,
     })

Aero_Stripped_Lowers_Consolidated.to_csv('MasterPriceTracker.csv')
```

I am receiving the error below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ComputerName/Documents/PyCharm_Projects/Aero Stripped Lower List/NewAeroStrippedLower.py", line 9, in <module>
    page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 640, in send
    adapter = self.get_adapter(url=request.url)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 731, in get_adapter
    raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for '%s'" % url)
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for '['https://www.aeroprecisionusa.com/ar15/lower-receivers/stripped-lowers?product_list_limit=all', 'https://www.aeroprecisionusa.com/ar15/lower-receivers/complete-lowers?product_list_limit=all']'
```

Thanks in advance for any help you may be able to provide!

Comment: change `page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)` to `page = requests.get(website, headers=headers)`

Comment: Thanks I’ll give that shot! Stupid question, do I keep the rest of the code indented or not? It seems weird too because some of the code won’t apply to every URL since there will be slight name changes to items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using requests.get() on a list. It's a simple mistake:

```py
# -- snip --

for website in url:
    headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0"}
    page = requests.get(website, headers=headers) # not 'url'
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

# -- snip --
```

Comment: Thanks you two for the help! That’s fixed the issue!